# Safari won't read .class img {} CSS

Tags: html, css, safari

This problem ONLY happens on Safari, all other browsers i've checked and they work fine (Opera, Chrome, Firefox).

I basically have a large list of small images used as links to different church websites. They are listed like so:

```
<div class="church"><img src="images/logos/antioch.png" style="width: 150px;" /><a href="#"><div class="caption"><br>Antioch House<br>Location</div></a></div>
```

And the CSS is as follows:

```
.church {
  overflow: hidden;
  position: relative;
  display: inline-block;
  width: 150px;
  height: 70px;
  -webkit-border-radius: 10px;
     -moz-border-radius: 10px;
       -o-border-radius: 10px;
          border-radius: 10px;
  border-style: solid;
  border-width: 1px;
  border-color: #000;
}

.church img {
  width: 150px;
}
```

I would like every image to be equal in length, so that if anyone was to add a new image, it would automatically size the logo to fit within the `.church` class `div`.

But for some reason, Safari (The only browser to do this) won't recognise the width I am trying to give to the `.church img` element. If I add `style="width: 150px;"` to the `img` tag in the index.html file, it works. But I feel like a disgraceful person to write that into 40 individual tags.

Perhaps i've just made a mistake somewhere that safari won't tolerate. (I am mostly a designer, so i do tend to make coding mistakes a lot)

Thanks for any help!

Comment: ever tried : <img class = "church" ?

Comment: Thanks! adding a class to the img was the best solution. Although, I still needed to use an outer div to hold some of the other elements together.